# Running Python config content in loop

Tags: python

I have an auto generated file which has data in format
**Config.py**

```
abc = {'Id':894, 'list':4, 'visibleCtx':60}
pqr = {'Id':84, 'list':3, 'visibleCtx':01}
xyz = {'Id':94, 'list':2, 'visibleCtx':10}
...
..
.
```

I want to loop through the contents of this config file like

```
while True:
    graphicalUI.setGraphsCtx(Config.(list_in_configFile))
```

But I am unable to see how this could be done?
I have tried RegEx to split each new line based on "=" and run it.

But can we do it with some other smoother way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import` the file as a module, and run `dir()` on the module object to obtain its variables.

You can also filter out the special `__` variables using a comprehension:

```
import module
var_names = [v for v in dir(module) if not v.startswith("__")]
```

Filter any other variables that have no interest. Once you have that, you can get the actual values:

```
config = { name: getattr(module, name) for name in var_names }
```

Comment: I will just try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

if the file is a valid python file why not import it as is and use the values.

also you could take a look after importing the file using the magic method `__dict__` [https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#object.**dict**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__)

another option would be to use another format like config file https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html or json https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html or yaml http://pyyaml.org/. these all create objects which you can iterate over

Comment: @slezica showed the same way and it has worked fine for me. thanks Ajurna. :)